# How to replace text in jquery and add formatting

Tags: jquery, css

I want to replace text with jquery / javascript but with a catch: the text is in bullet format.

The HTML markup would be:

```
<ul id="text_to_be_replaced">
  <li>list item 01</li>
  <li>list item 02</li>
  <li>list item 03</li>
</ul>
```

But I have no idea how to utilize this in jquery / javascript other than giving each "li" an id.
I want to do something like this:

```
function change_text(){
  $("#text_to_be_replaced").text("//I want to format the text in here to
  display in bullet format.");
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: what is the expected output format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) method if you want to pass the new contents in one go

```
function change_text(){
  $("#text_to_be_replaced").html("<li> item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, works perfectly! I didn't actually know jquery had a `.html()` method, I know of the `.innerHTML` in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Loop each li?

```
$('#text_to_be_replaced > li').each(function(i) {
   //Do your thang

   //$(this) refers to each of the li being iterated
   $(this).html('new text');

   //i is the iteration index, 0-indexed
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, creative solution! I can't yet vote I'm afraid, not enough rep points. But 1 up!

Answer (score 0):

then you can use html instead of text

```
$("#text_to_be_replaced").html("//I want to format the text in here to
  display in bullet format.");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#text_to_be_replaced li').each(function() {
    $(this).html('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#text_to_be_replaced').children('li').each(function(){
     $(this).html('replaced')
});
```

Use `html()` and `children()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function change_text(){
    $("#text_to_be_replaced > li").html(function(index, value){
        return value.replace(/list\s+/, '')
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CeFpR/)